# celery memory management

Tags: python, celery

I have a 3 celery nodes running between 6 and 8 workers each and my tasks tend to use a lot of memory. It seems that when the tasks finish, they aren't releasing the memory. Is there a way to either tell the worker process to die and restart after execution completes, or improve celery's garbage collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those workers you could set [max-tasks-per-child-setting](http://celeryproject.org/docs/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting) to one.